# How to round to a certain number of significant figures using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

**Edit: This part is solved!**

So I have a bunch of calculations in a program I'm making, and the numbers are getting so long that I'm getting overflow errors. It's resulting from things like dividing a 50 digit number by another 50 digit number. I need a way to round specific numbers to a certain amount of significant digits.

Here's some more information. First of all, all of the numbers I will be rounding will always be less than 1. The numbers can get as small as to the 1E-50. I only care about the first 10 or so significant digits. I just need a way to round it off to around ten sig figs before moving on to the next calculation in order to prevent overflow errors. That, and having a number go out to 50 figures is very useless.

I was thinking of maybe looping through the number, digit by digit? The program could add 1 to a counter when the number is equal to zero, and then break out of the loop once it hits anything other than zero. Then the next step could truncate the number to that counter plus however many significant digits I want.

So for .000001234567812345678 for example. It would return 5 zeroes. If I wanted ten significant figures, I would do five + ten = 15. The program would then only keep the first 15 digits after the decimal, so the number would be truncated to .000001234567812.

Another idea might be using the log. Then the power the new number would be raised to would be the number of zeroes in front of the significant digits.

What I don't know is, first of all, how to go through a number digit by digit, and checking if each number is a zero. I also don't know how to truncate a number to a certain amount of digits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit: This part is not solved.**

I would feel bad making another post so soon, so I'm going to ask the question here. If it's not answered in 20 minutes or so, maybe I'll make another post. Why isn't this working?

```
Sub Rounding()
    Tracker = 0
    For i = 1 To 10
        Tracker = Tracker + 1
        Cells(1, Tracker) = Rnd
        Cells(1, Tracker) = Application.Evaluate("=Round(Cells(1, Tracker), 4 - (Int(Log(Cells(1,Tracker))) + 1))")
    Next
    Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error, #NAME?, in every single cell. This should round each number to four significant digits.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Excel can only work with 15 digits of precision: your 50-digit numbers cannot be represented "correctly".  See Jerry's answer here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/391191-why-is-excel-changing-the-last-2-digits-of-a-17-digit-num-to-00-a.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your value is in A2, try either of these:

```
=ROUND(A2, 3-(INT(LOG(A2))+1))
```

or

```
=ROUND(A2,3-LEN(INT(A2)))
```

Taken from [here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071208084527AApV4c4).

Comment: This works very well! So the number in red is how many significant figures I want. How would I actually use this in VBA? I tried `Range("A4") = Application.Worksheetfunction.Round(A2,3-(Int(Log(A2))+1))` and it didn't work. I keep getting a "Invalid procedure call or argument".

Comment: Try `Range("A2")` instead of `A2`.

Comment: I changed it to `Range("A4") = Application.Evaluate("=Round(A2,3-(Int(Log(A2))+1))")` and it worked! It does round the last number, but I can just add one extra digit, and it shouldn't matter. Thank you!

Comment: Do you happen to know why the program I made using this isn't working? I put it in the above text, below my original question.

Comment: @TheTreeMan - Sorry, I was at lunch :)  Siddharth Rout's answer looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to loop when there is already a function which gives you what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim someNumber As Double

    '~~> .000001234567812345678
    someNumber = 1.23456781234568E-06

    '~~> This will give you .000001234567812
    Debug.Print Round(someNumber, 15)
End Sub
```

Comment: It won't be the same number of zeroes every time. It can range from no zeroes to fifty zeroes. I could use the Round() function, but I'd need a way of detecting how many zeroes there are, so I know how many digits to round it to.

Comment: Using LittleBobbyTables's method, I got the program to work! However, after editing the program to move and apply to cells as they're filled, the program "broke". I put the code in question above, below the other question I had. Why does it keep giving me a #NAME? error? Is it because of the Cells() reference inside? It worked in a module I was testing out, for individual cells, until I changed it to move with the Tracker.

Comment: Change `Cells(1, Tracker) = Application.Evaluate("=Round(Cells(1, Tracker), 4 - (Int(Log(Cells(1,Tracker))) + 1))")` to `Cells(1, Tracker) = Application.Evaluate("=Round(Cells(1," & Tracker & "), 4 - (Int(Log(Cells(1," & Tracker & "))) + 1))")` Tracker is a variable and not a string ;)

Comment: Ahh, such a stupid mistake! Thank you.

Edit: It's actually giving me the same error?

Comment: I put it into Excel, and changed it up a bit so it didn't rely on tracker anymore, just to see if it worked, and I got the #NAME? error in each cell. I put in `=ROUND(Cells(1,1), 4 - (INT(LOG(Cells(1,1))) + 1))`. If I click the error it says "This formula contains unrecognized text".

Comment: Ah! Cells() is not a formula ;) `Application.Evaluate("=Round(" & Cells(1, Tracker) & ", 4 - (Int(Log(" & Cells(1, Tracker) & ")) + 1))")`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in excel worksheet, one can use:
=ROUND(A2, 3-(INT(LOG(A2))+1))

but in VBA, the code becomes:
=Round(Range("A2"), 3-(Int(Log(Range("A2"))/log(10#))+1))

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if 3-(Int(Log(Range("A2"))/log(10#))+1)) is negative (i.e. if there are more significant figures before the decimal point than you wish to round the number to). An alternative is

```
Public Function round_sigfig(ByVal myval As Double, ByVal fignum As Integer) As Double
factor = 10 ^ (fignum - (Int(Log(myval) / Log(10#))) - 1)
round_sigfig = Round(myval * factor, 0) / factor
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `roundSignif` rounds `x` to `sd` significant digits. Works for all numbers (`x < 1` as well as `x >= 1`, also all negative numbers and `0`)

```
' Round `x` to `sd` significant digits
Function roundSignif(x As Double, sd As Integer) As Double
    Dim oom As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    
    oom = orderOfMag(x)
    d = -oom + sd - 1
    
    If d >= 0 Then
        roundSignif = Round(x, d)
    Else
        ' rounding to a negative number of digits is not possible
        roundSignif = Round(x * 10 ^ d, 0) / 10 ^ d
    End If
End Function

' Return order of magnitude of `x`
Function orderOfMag(x As Double) As Integer
    If x = 0 Then
        orderOfMag = 0
    ElseIf Abs(x) < 1 Then
        orderOfMag = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(x)), 0)
    Else
        orderOfMag = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(WorksheetFunction.Log10(Abs(x)), 0)
    End If
End Function
```

testing...

```
Sub testRoundSignif()
    Dim x As Variant
    For Each x In Array(0, 1, 11, 111, -111, 0.0987, -0.123)
        Debug.Print (x & " -> " & roundSignif(CDbl(x), 2))
    Next x
End Sub

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
11 -> 11
111 -> 110
-111 -> -110
0.0987 -> 0.099
-0.123 -> -0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Version without using WorksheetFunction for portability with other vba platforms
test: 101.538=101.6, 10.1254=10.13, 3.64589=3.646, 2.1=2.1, 35845.65=35850,-25.438 = -25.44, -15687.354 = -1569, -100=-100, 84354.34=84360

```
Sub test()
    Dim testStr As String
    Dim num, testNum As Variant
    
    testStr = "101.538, 10.1254, 3.64589, 2.1, 35845.65, -25.438, -15687.354, -100, 84354.34"
    testNum = Split(testStr, ",")
    
    For Each num In testNum
        Debug.Print roundupSignifDigits(num, 4)
    Next num
End Sub


Function roundupSignifDigits(inputNum, signifDigits As Integer)

    'rounds up the inputNum to number of significant Digits
    'Example Usage -> Debug.Print roundupSignifDigits(num, 4)
    
    Dim flag, i, NegFact As Integer
    Dim mult  As Double
    
    'If inputNum is negative then take absolute value and then multiply answer at end by NegFact to make it negative again
    If inputNum < 0 Then
        NegFact = -1
        inputNum = Abs(inputNum)
        Else: NegFact = 1
    End If
    
    mult = 10 ^ (signifDigits - 1)
    
    'first check if number is greater than 1 or less than 1
    If inputNum > 1 Then flag = 1 Else flag = 0
    
    Select Case flag
        Case 1
            Do
                i = i + 1
            Loop Until inputNum / 10 ^ i < 1
            inputNum = inputNum / 10 ^ (i - 1)
            roundupSignifDigits = NegFact * Int(inputNum * -mult) / -mult * 10 ^ (i - 1)
    
        Case 0
            Do
                i = i - 1
            Loop Until inputNum / 10 ^ i > 1
            inputNum = inputNum / 10 ^ i
            roundupSignifDigits = NegFact * Int(inputNum * -mult) / -mult * 10 ^ i
    End Select

End Function
```