# Is there a way to do 5 different number formats in one cell or write VBA script to produce a number format based on the value?

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, number-formatting

The data I produce has to have specific number formatting which depends on how large or how small the number is.

Numbers >=100 shouldn't have any decimal places, >=10 should have one decimal place (even if it is a zero), >=1 should have two decimal places (even if the last is a zero), 0.999-0.001 should have three decimal places (even if the last is a zero), and 0.0009-0.0001 should have four decimal places, again regardless of what the number in the last decimal place is.

So essentially I need a code, or way, to look at a number and give me those specific decimal places. I know I can format them individually, but we are talking thousands upon thousands of numbers that I would be formatting. I have tried using the round function but it won't give me trailing zeros.

This is currently what I am using as a function on the spreadsheet which works for everything but trailing zeros:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A$21,'Copied Data'!$A$15:$FL$140,23)>'Copied Data'!U$7,IF('Copied Data'!W16<0.001,ROUND('Copied Data'!W16,4),IF('Copied Data'!W16>=0.001,ROUND('Copied Data'!W16,3),IF('Copied Data'!W16>0.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!W16,2),IF('Copied Data'!W16>9.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!W16,1),IF('Copied Data'!W16>99.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!W16,0)," "))))),"<"&IF('Copied Data'!U$7<0.001,ROUND('Copied Data'!U$7,4),IF('Copied Data'!U$7>=0.0001,ROUND('Copied Data'!U$7,3),IF('Copied Data'!U$7>0.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!U$7,2),IF('Copied Data'!U$7>9.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!U$7,1),IF('Copied Data'!U$7>99.999,ROUND('Copied Data'!U$7,0)," "))))))
```

If there is a better way to do this, or a way to write a macro for it in VBA, that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried writing a macro?  You can record yourself setting the different formats you need then use that as a starting point.

Comment: I think you can use Conditional Formatting

Comment: Sounds like you want to round to significant figures, so the following may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742994/how-to-round-to-a-certain-number-of-significant-figures-using-excel-vba

Comment: @Tragamor kind of, using the function they have here almost works, but when the number is something like "0.080345" I will get "0.0803" when I need it to be "0.080".

Comment: @TimWilliams I have never done that before! I am very much a newbie in terms of using VBA. Would it know why I am setting those formats and how to apply them?

Comment: No it would not know why you're doing what you're doing, but the recorded code would give you a start with the VBA and the number formats.

Comment: @TimWilliams so I had VBA record what I did and I can see it showing the various formats for the specific cells I changed but how do I make it recognize that a number between 0.0001-0.00099 should have 4 decimal places, 0.001-0.999 should have 3 decimal places, etc.?

Comment: You'd loop over the cells to be formatted and use something like `If cell.Value >  0.0001 And cell.Value <= 0.00099 Then cell.NumberFormat = [your format here]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will deal with modifiers:

```vb
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, op, v

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100") 'for example, or = Selection

For Each c In rng.Cells
    v = Trim(c.Value)
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        'if the value has a modifier, remove it
        op = ""
        If v Like ">*" Or v Like "<*" Then
            op = Left(v, 1)
            v = Trim(Right(v, Len(v) - 1))
        End If
    
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            v = CDbl(v)
            If v > 0.0001 And v <= 0.00099 Then
                c.Value = v
                c.NumberFormat = op & "[format1]" 'include any modifier in the format
            ElseIf v > 0.001 And v <= 0.999 Then
                c.Value = v
                c.NumberFormat = op & "[format2]"
            Else
                'you should probably include a general format so all
                ' cells which might have modifiers get the same treatment
            End If
            'add other cases as needed
        End If
    End If

Next c
```

Where [format1] etc are the formats you got from your macro recording

Note that any modifiers are no longer part of the value of the cell after this - they exist only in the cell format.  That means you can work with the cells as numbers, but depending on what you need to do eventually it might or might not be appropriate.

If you just want to change the format of the numeric part of the cell value, then you could do something like:

```
c.Value = Application.Text(v, op & "0.0000")
```

Comment: This is great and works! Thank you! Another question, some of my data contains "<" and then a value (<0.005 for example). Can I make the macro recognize the "<" and the cell value, and do the same number formatting? I believe this would have to use some sort of string function but I am not sure. I am also not sure if I would need another section of this code or just add to the first If statement.

Comment: If you have modifiers then that's more difficult, and the best approach would depend on exactly what you need to do with those values "downstream".  You can build a modifier into the number format by prepending it to your existing format "< 0.00" for example.

Comment: So essentially I need my number formats to be as described for any numbers on there. However, some have a "<" in front of them which causes this particular macro not to work for those values. It works perfectly for cells that are just a number and don't contain "<" at the beginning. I need to format the numbers downstream, but I can't add "<" before all of the numbers. Something like " if it contains "<" then look at the numbers downstream and if they are between x and y give this format" so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you! The macro is giving me an error for the Trim(c.Value) formula. The error is 2042, so #N/A. I'm thinking it can't see the cell as a value with the "<" in it which is causing issue.

Comment: What's the actual value in `c` when it errors?

Comment: Interestingly enough I went to run the macro again and I didn't get an error...and then tried again and I got the error. I think it didn't like the use of c.Value because it works with c.Text. Everything else seems to be working. I used the Application.Text function you described in the code for all of the "c.Value =" portions of the code and it all seems to be working well. I'll have to look deeper into everything to see if there are any issues but I think it is good to go. I appreciate all of your help!